# Passing dynamic terraform variables in json using shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, scripting, terraform, amazon-eks

I am writing a shell script for replacing a keyword in a json file with a dynamic value using shell.

123.json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/role1",
            "arn:aws:iam::yyyyyy:role/role2"
          ]
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {}
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am getting the values of role1 and role2 as the terraform variables in shell script

shell.sh file has

```
echo $role1
echo $role2

$ cat 123.json | sed -n '/role1/ s/role1/$role/ p' 
$ cat 123.json | sed -n '/role1/ s/role1/$role/ p'
```

But the role1 and role2 are not getting updated. Can someone help me out.

Comment: I don't get it - do you use a variable called `role1`, `role2` or `role`?

Comment: @smac2020 role1 and role2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sed command doesn't work because shell does not expand variables
in single quotes. But sed is not a good tool for editing structured
format such as JSON - `jq` is a better choice:

```
jq --argjson foo "\"$role1\"" '.Statement[].Principal.AWS[0] |= sub("role1$";$foo)' < 123.json
jq --argjson foo "\"$role2\"" '.Statement[].Principal.AWS[1] |= sub("role2$";$foo)' < 123.json
```

`"\"$role2\""` creates a jq variable from shell variables with literal
double quotes added at the beginning and at the end.

To save output back to file you need to use external utilities because
`jq` doesn't have -i option that tools such as sed have. You can
either use `sponge` which is a part of
[moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils):

```
$ jq --argjson foo "\"$role1\"" '.Statement[].Principal.AWS[0] |= sub("role1$";$foo)' < 123.json | sponge 123.json
$ jq --argjson foo "\"$role2\"" '.Statement[].Principal.AWS[1] |= sub("role2$";$foo)' < 123.json | sponge 123.json
```

or manually write to a temporary file and move file in place of
123.json:

```
$ temp="$(mktemp)"
$ jq --argjson foo "\"$role1\"" '.Statement[].Principal.AWS[0] |= sub("role1$";$foo)' < 123.json  > "$temp"
$ mv "$temp" 123.json
$ temp="$(mktemp)"
$ jq --argjson foo "\"$role2\"" '.Statement[].Principal.AWS[1] |= sub("role2$";$foo)' < 123.json > "$temp"
$ mv "$temp" 123.json
```

Comment: Can you try explaining what are u doing as part of it.  jq --argjson foo "\"$role1\""

Comment: I ran the above command its updating the file but not saving it. Can you pls help.